# How to update PHP version 5.3 on linux vps

Tags: php, linux, vps, plesk

Sorry if this has already been answered but im looking for a user friendly version for beginners on how to update my PHP version on Plesk.

I'm currently using 5.3 and i have no other options to chose another version or to update it?

I Understand i am more than likely going to have to use putty to update it but that's as far as i know..

Anyone able to help me?

Comment: [maybe try this](http://www.thelinuxchef.com/to-upgrade-php-and-mysql-on-plesk-running-linux-server-pleask-running-linux-server/)

Comment: Everytime i try to follow it it keeps saying no such file or directory :(

Answer (score 1):

What is your Plesk version? Since Plesk 12.0 multiple PHP feature is implemented in Plesk - https://kb.odin.com/en/125146

Comment: Thanks Igor i managed to sort it out in the end.. When i was updating the php version (for someone reason) it was deleting plesk. So i installed a seperate version of php.